# Insert with parameters

Tags: database, vb.net, vbscript, ado.net

I should change all queries to use parameters to protect app from SQL injection.

Current insert sample which works is:

```
If Len(ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO ICE_Order_Details(Order_ID, Product_ID, License_Type_ID, Maintenance_ID, Qty, Shareit_Running_No, Price, Total) VALUES(" & OrderID & ", " & ProductID & ", " & LicenseTypeID & ", " & MaintenanceID & ", " & Val(Request("QUANTITY")) & ", " & Val(Request("RUNNING_NO")) & ", " & Price & ", " & Price * Val(Request("QUANTITY")) & ")")) > 0 Then
    'SendBadRequest "Could not run insert Order detail query"
```

Can you help me to write parametric query instead of this?
I tried a lot of ways to do this but here is below last one.

```
Dim ConnString As New SqlConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB.0;Data Source=something;Initial Catalog=something;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=something;Password=something")
Dim SqlString As String ="INSERT INTO ICE_Order_Details(Order_ID, Product_ID, License_Type_ID, Maintenance_ID, Qty, Shareit_Running_No, Price, Total) VALUES(@OrderID, @ProductID, @LicenseTypeID, @MaintenanceID, @Qty, @RunningNo, @Price, @Total)"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseTypeID", LicenseTypeID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaintenanceID", MaintenanceID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Val(Request("QUANTITY")))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunningNo", Val(Request("RUNNING_NO")))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", Price * Val(Request("QUANTITY")))
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Using
```

**Edit:** It still doesn't work. Here is my current code for adding parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderId
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ProductID
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LicenseTypeID
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaintenanceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MaintenanceID
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(Request("QUANTITY"))
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RunningNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(Request("RUNNING_NO"))
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Money.Parse(Price)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Money.Parse(Price * Int32.Parse(Request("QUANTITY")))
```

**Edit:** I changed my insert query to test only insert with parameters. But it don't work

```
Dim ConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB_Connection_String0").ConnectionString

Dim SqlString As String ="INSERT INTO Unsubscribed(E-Mail) VALUES(@E-Mail)"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@E-Mail", SqlDbType.nvarchar).Value = "testiram@obrisime.sada"
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Using
```

here is error which i got (it marked 'As') if I change connection string it show error on next 'As' in code with same error message

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> /Test.asp, line 8
>
> Dim ConnString As String =
>   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB_Connection_String0").ConnectionString
>   ---------------^

Comment: Can you show the *exact* error message?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, except the use of the `AddWithValue` method. this method infers the data type of the parameter and can sometimes get it wrong. better use Add. i.e `cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderId`

Comment: I can't see error message. This is big problem here. because this page call ecomerce site and I can't debug it. I got only generic error message from ecomerce site

Comment: Please follow Zohar's advice. Also note that you should **not** use the "magic" `Val` function. Use the static Parse (or TryParse) methods like `Int32.Parse` and `Decimal.Parse`.

Comment: It still don't work I try change way for adding parameters. You can see in post new code (in edit section)

Comment: You are mixing DBObjects.  You have a connection object for SQL Server (looks like 2 connection objects), an OleDB command object and using SQL Server dbType enums.  What is the DB?

Comment: All, i change my query a litle to try just insert with parameters but it still doesn't work. See - edit in post

Comment: That is not a VB.NET error message, sounds like you tagged your question wrong too

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for this

Thanks all for help!

here is code below which work fine

```
<% 
Dim oConn, oCmd, ds, sql
    p1 = "test"
    p2 = "test"
    p3 = "test"
ds = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=___;Initial Catalog=___;User ID=___;Password=___;"
sql = "INSERT INTO table (prop1, prop2, prop3) VALUES (?,?,?)"

Set oConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open ds

Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
oCmd.CommandText = sql
oCmd.CommandType = 1
oCmd.Parameters(0) = p1
oCmd.Parameters(1) = p2
oCmd.Parameters(2) = p3
oCmd.Execute()
oConn.close
Set oConn=nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use sqlhelper class file by microsoft which i think is best for this cause and is relatively easy to use and shortens code by much. e.g
in save click event it will go like this

```
sqlParameter[] parem=
{
new sqlparameter("@value1"urcontrol.text),
new sqlparameter("@value2"urcontrol.text),
new sqlparameter("@value3"urcontrol.text)
};
sqlhelper.executenonquery (connectionstring,commandtype.storeprocedure,"ProcedureName",parem);
```

rest will be handled automatically by sqlhelper class file